# recreate screen similar to the settings screen on the android tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create a screen similar to the settings screen on the android tablet. The screen is split in two with a list on the right. When a item is selected on the right the details are shown on the left. I also want to have similar graphics in terms of the littel arrow that shows which item has been selected. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It is call **`Fragment Activity`** you can use this for same as settings layout in tablet.

For more information plz do search about **`Fragment Activity`**

Here is [Best Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Comment: hi thanks for that. Ive managed to get an example working fine but how can i add the little touches like a little arrow as on the settings screen that points to the selected item